# Drop drop-down in a select multiple tag form field

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My html code is the following:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

which gives result: [output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTIYy.png)

What I want is: [output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJUwI.png)

without the drop-down and showing all the possible options.
Anyone know how to implement that feature?
Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this ? I added the size to 5 and in the styles put the overflow(the bar on the side) to auto.
Hope it'll help you :)

```html
<div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <select size="5" style="overflow:auto" multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select multiple class="form-control" size="5" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below CSS rule in style tag,it will remove your scrollbars but it will still be scrollable :

```css
<style> 
    #exampleFormControlSelect2::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none;
    } 
</style>
```